# Angular2 pass data to modal

Tags: html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-modal

i'm new in angular2 + typescript. And i need realize confirmation modal by click on button in table

**This is table**

```
<div style="margin-top: 10px">
    <table id="recruitersTable" class="table table-striped center" [ngBusy]="data">
        <tr>
            <th>{{ 'RECRUITER_NAME_AND_SURNANE_COLUMN' | translate }}</th>
            <th>{{ 'RECRUITER_CODE_COLUMN' | translate }}</th>
            <th>{{ 'RECRUITER_ACTION_DOLUMN' | translate}}</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let recruiter of recruiters">
            <td>{{ recruiter.Name }}</td>
            <td>{{ recruiter.Code }}</td>
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-xs btn-default" data-target="#confirm" role="button" data-toggle="modal">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></span>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**This is confirmation modal**

```
<div id="confirm" class="modal fade in" aria-labelledby="modallabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
            <h3 id="modalLabael">Block recruiter</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <h3 id="modalLabael">Are you sure that you want block this recruiter?</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="BlockRecruiter(recruiter.code)">Block</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And i need implement function by click 'success' on confirm modal, but data in another div. Can someone explain me?

Comment: Is the modal a separate component or the same one?

Comment: separate component,

Answer (score 0):

You could either use EventEmitter if your modal component is contained in the parent component - Check here --> https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/EventEmitter-class.html

Or you could use a service that returns a subject as an observable. The parent component can subscribe to the observable while the modal alerts the service on confirmation. Check how the alert.service has been written and used here --> [Angular 2: Displaying icons in navbar on authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40264705/angular-2-displaying-icons-in-navbar-on-authentication/40285638?noredirect=1#comment67864795_40285638)